# Node-sass or SASS for React project

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I just wanted to know what were the main difference of using node-sass or just SASS in a React project that has been bootstrapped with CRA? Is there benefits of one over the other? or are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

node-sass are Node.js bindings to LibSass (a C/C++ implementation of a Sass compiler) and are both deprecated.

I would use [the latest Dart Sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)

Comment: So In other words the latest sass version is dart-sass? that link takes me to the npm page to install sass?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @sole Yes and yes. Other packages are not under development